# Is "loose motion" a synonym of "diarrhea"?

Tags: word-usage, slang

I heard someone say:

> She's having **loose motion**.

I couldn't get it. So then asked it from one of my friend, and she said, it's a synonym of *diarrhea*. Is that a correct noun?

Comment: It is perhaps more of a euphemism.  A closer synonym or description might be *loose watery stools*

Comment: You probably heard "loose movements".  "Bowel movement" is a more polite way to say "defecation".  And applying the adjective "loose" implies some degree of diarrhea.

Comment: Or she's dancer who had formerly been a little stiff and has now limbered up. We won't know unless we had more context.

Answer (score 3):

[Motion](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/motion) can indeed mean

> 7. (Brit)
>     a)the evacuation of the bowels 
>     b)excrement

As you will see this is primarily a British English usage.

Given the response you received on inquiry, 'loose motion' will indeed have meant diarrhea (or as it is spelled in British English, *diarrhoea*)

Comment: But 'motion' in this sense is usually count [[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/motion)] and usually used in plural form. 'She's having loose motions.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth by contrast, in the US "movement" would be more common and could be used in the singular (to describe a single event or the product thereof) or in the plural to describe an ongoing medical state.

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford English Dictionary has this (note the one I put into bold);

11.11 The involuntary action of the intestines, leading to discharge of their contents; an evacuation of the bowels. Also, chiefly in pl., that which is evacuated; the fæces.

1598 Shakes. Merry W. iii. i. 105 Shall I loose my Doctor? No, hee giues me the Potions and the Motions.    1766 [Anstey] Bath Guide ii. 50 We must swallow a Potion For driving out Wind after every Motion.    **1786 R. Willan in Med. Commun. II. 118 He had‥two or three loose motions.**    1843 R. J. Graves Syst. Clin. Med. x. 111 Those who are dissatisfied with less than two or three motions in the day.    1871 G. H. Napheys Prev. & Cure Dis. iii. ix. 995 The motions of the bowels present a pale drab or clay color.    1897 Allbutt's Syst. Med. III. 737 In sprue the motions are generally very frothy.

Comment: I'd say the first subsense (3 given) is rare in everyday English; 'She has loose motions/_movements_' [as Hot Licks suggests] is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it's more like the slang or the accepted or known phrase, I know "loose motion" is the common term for diarrhea in Pakistan. You rarely hear the word diarrhea there, but "loose motion" is used often (I'd assume doctors know it's called diarhea, but would call it "loose motion" there, as that's the known phrase.)

Comment: It would be rare to hear the singular form in the UK, Mohammed.

Answer (score 1):

> She's having loose motion.

This is Indian English and perfectly acceptable in Indian English.

In British and American English, the same sentence would be

She has diarrhoea(BE) / diarrhea (AE)

You will note that in BE/AE

(i) "loose motion" is not used,

(ii) "loose motion" would be countable -> loose motion**s**.

(iii) the continuous form of the verb "to have" would be incorrect in AE/BE.